# How to monitor event-consumer lag in Kafka with micrometer gauge metric?

Tags: java, spring-boot, metrics, micrometer

I want to publish a metric "gauge" for the current lag of the consumer(Event listener) in Kafka. I want to monitor whether the messages are consumed at a good speed or whether it is too slow. The metrics are eventually connected with CloudWatch. I am using Springboot, Micrometer library, CloudWatch.

In the event handler or the listener(consumer), I did the following -

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "your-topic",filter ="my-filter")
public void listenerExample(CloudEvent event, @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC) String topicName,
        Consumer<?, ?> consumer) {
    String currentLag = consumer.metrics().values().stream().filter(m -> "records-lag-     max".equals(m.metricName().name()))
            .map(Metric::metricValue).map(Object::toString).distinct()
            .collect(Collectors.joining(";", "[Kafka current consumer lag]", " records"));
    LOGGER.info(lag);

//The currentLag is a String here. We need to convert it to an Integer but the String is pretty big due to //the prefix and the suffix. Do we need to substring the number from the string?    
    
    meterRegistry.gauge("consumer.lag",Integer.parseInt(currentLag));
}
```

The connection to the CloudWatch with the help of CloudWatchConfig(), CloudWatchMeterRegistry() is done and this registry is used further to publish the metrics.

```
MeterRegistry registry = new SimpleMeterRegistry();
      registry = new CloudWatchMeterRegistry(new CloudWatchConfig() {
        private final Map<String, String> configuration =
          Map.of("cloudwatch.namespace", "Name/" + namespace, "cloudwatch.step",            Duration.ofMinutes(5).toString());
```

However I do not see any metric "consumer.lag" in the CloudWatch. Am I doing it correctly? I am still not sure how should I implement

> meterRegistry.gauge("consumer.lag",Integer.parseInt(currentLag));

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look at [`KafkaMetrics`](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/529a792f01c757be02a0e5f04b1d669f78a1eda3/micrometer-core/src/main/java/io/micrometer/core/instrument/binder/kafka/KafkaMetrics.java), it should provide you this information (and more).

Also, please be careful doing this on your own:

1. Micrometer `Gauge`s maintain only a weak reference to the object being observed by default, so as not to prevent garbage collection of the object. When GC happens and the object is collected, it will not be available to the Gauge anymore, you need to maintain a strong reference, see the docs: [Gauges](https://docs.micrometer.io/micrometer/reference/concepts/gauges.html).
2. `consumer.metrics()` is very tricky in Kafka. The Kafka client sometimes drops the references to all of these metrics and recreates them while Micrometer or you try to use them. If you look into `KafkaMetrics`, it tries to sole this (hack this around) by re-registering meters.

A real solution to the issue with the Kafka client would be Kafka instrumenting itself using Micrometer, please if you think you could also benefit from this, leave a comment on this issue so that Kafka devs could add this/accept a PR: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-15191

Comment: Upvoting this. WIth that said, there is a metric called "kafka_consumer_fetch_manager_records_lag" exposed by the client already. I thought this is what the author needed. If this is not the case, what is "kafka_consumer_fetch_manager_records_lag" purpose?